# HP DL380 G7 Disk swap to a HP DL380 G6

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

The HP DL380 G7 has 3 SAS disks in RAID 5 configuration. I need to change that server to another task and instead of make a clean install on the HP DL380 G6 can i just swap the 3 disks from HP DL380 G7 to the HP DL380 G6?

I expect some driver issues maybe on the OS itself because the processor is different.

They both use Smart Array P410i, if i power down the machines swap the disk by the same order
will the RAID 5 configuration remain and the OS will boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be no problem, as the RAID metadata is on the harddisks themselves.
You only need to make sure that both controllers use the same firmware (suggested using the last, so you might want to upgrade first).

Also see the Smart Array manual by HP, page 81-82: "Moving drives and arrays":

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01608507/c01608507.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There are no issues making that switch. There won't be any driver issues. The DL380 G6 and the DL380 G7 have the same P410 RAID controller. It may make sense to run the [HP Firmware DVD](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-94560dcc34e845edbb13a26792%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) or [HP Service Pack DVD](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-7a8fd7561fb340388b2109cbed%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) to bring the server hardware up-to-date before or after making the switch, as there have been some major feature changes during the life of the components involved.

In general, the Smart Array RAID metadata is stored with the drives, so make sure you try to keep the disks in the same order. Watch the POST messages to ensure that the array is recognized before booting.